# Determining how to find $P(X \leq Y )$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let X and Y denote two independent continuous random variables, where $X \sim \text{Exponential(1)}$ and $Y \sim \text{Exponential(2)}$.

Calculate $P(X \leq Y)$

I know that i have:
$$
F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-1x}, \; \; \; x >  0 
$$
and
$$
F_Y(y) = 1 - e^{-2x}, \; \; \; x > 0 
$$
By using the law of total probability i think that i can get this:
$$
P(X \leq Y) = \sum_{y = 1}^{x} P(X \leq Y | Y = y)P(Y = y) 
$$
But if i'm going to be honest then i don't know if i'm using the law of total probability correct or even if i'm supposed to use it.

Update: Thanks for the help i'm pretty sure i understand it now and know how to solve it.

Comment: Since Y is continuous r.v. $P(Y=y)=0$ and the sum by $y$ should be replaced by integral.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

By independence, the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$ is given by
$$
      f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = 2e^{-x - 2y}1_{x > 0}1_{y > 0}
$$

Then, the probability to be calculated is
$$
     \mathbb{P}(X \le Y) = \iint_{0 < x \le y} 2e^{-x - 2y}dxdy
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, their joint density is:
$$f(x, y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y) = 2e^{-(x+2y)},$$ which is defined on non negative real numbers. We want the probability of $y$ taking any value in $[0,\infty)$ and $x$ taking any value in $[0,y]$, so $$P(X\leq Y)=\int_{0}^\infty\int_0^y 2e^{-(x+2y)}dxdy=\frac{1}{3}.$$